# Подскажите решение для автообновления моего софта у клиентов

Tags: update

Друзья, подскажите готовое решение для автообновления моего софта у клиентов.
Возможно есть компании которые такое решение предлагают.
Какой нибудь сервер автообновлений.
Выслушаю все ваши мысли.

Нужно, чтобы у клиента софт обновлялся атоматически.

Что мне нужно:

- система сборки проектов и прогонки юнит тестов.
- система автоматического обновления установленного у клиентов софта

Comment: Для Windows и OS X есть опенсорсный [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel), например. Но он решает только вопросы обновления. Сборка и прогонка тестов это отдельная задача, которая может в случае успеха заканчиваться публикацией сборки в Squirrel. Для этого решений вагон, хотя на вершине этого вагона нынче Jenkins.

Comment: У меня приложение должно собираться под Windows и под Linux. Как это можно организовать в Jenkins? Это нужно два Jenkins-а ставить с разными настройками или есть более изящный метод решения сборки?

Comment: Может вы знаете другие платные или бесплатные решения наподобие Squirrel. В будущем хотим сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от ключа обновлять только те продукты которые привязаны к этому ключу. Может быть есть что-то подобное и уже реализовано.

Comment: Надёжных DRM-систем, кроме разве что крайне инвазивного, тяжёлого, дорогущего и только-под-Windows Denuvo (печально известного в индустрии видеоигр), я не знаю. Бесплатных и надёжных точно нет. А в Jenkins, как и в любом уважающем себя CI, есть "агенты", их у одного инстанса может быть несколько, с разными средами.